# How to work with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

In Swift, we mostly use many **references** of classes like ,

1. UITableView
2. UIStepper
3. UILabel
4. NSTimer
5. UISlider and etc..

one example:

> var slider : UISlider!

My question is whether we have to create all these as **weak** refernces by **prefixing** it as **weak**, so that ARC will not have a strong hold on it so **ARC** can delete it as when needed or just creating a **strong reference** and make it to **nil** at the **viewDidUnload** deligate ??

example :

> slider = nil

To the point I actually **don't** know how to **manually use ARC** or manually handling ARC is not at all needed ?? I have no idea about this meamory handling

Pls do share if u ever came across this and found a solution...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: ARC will deallocate an object if there are no longer strong references to it. You do not need to set the slider to `nil` because that will happen automatically when the view controller and view are deallocated. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: I **highly** recommend [this article on ARC](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html). It is written using Obj-C instead of Swift, but since Swift still uses Cocoa and runs on the Obj-C runtime, it is completely relevant. The article gets deep into how the compiler analyzes your code and inserts memory management into it. It's a great read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC (`Automatic Reference Counting)` in Swift is explained pretty well in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Below you can find a very simple recap of 4 important aspects of ARC.

### **1. Basics**

ARC associates to each instance of a Class a `retainCount` integer.
This value represents the number of strong references to that specific instance.
When this number becomes 0 then the memory used by the instance is freed.

```
class Something {}
var aVariable = Something()
// now the reference counting for this particular instance of Something is 1
```

Now our instance of `Something` is keept in memory since its `retainCount` value is `1`.

```
var anotherVariable = aVariable
```

Now we have `2` strong references to our instance of `Something`. Good! Its `retainCount` now is `2` and the instance is still kept in memory!

```
aVariable = nil
```

The `retainCount` has just become `1`. No problem, the instance is still in memory.

```
anotherVariable = nil
```

Finally the `retainCount` of our instance has become `0`. This means that the instance has been freed and can no longer be accessed.

### **2. Should you set to nil your variables when you're done with them?**

**Nope.** Infact when a variable goes out of scope ARC automatically decrease the `retainCount` of the referenced instance.

In the following example, before the last `}` the `retainCount` of the instance of `Something` gets decreased and reach value `0` (and is freed).

```
func doSomethingUseful() {
    let something = Something()
    // ... do very important stuff here
}
```

So in a common scenario you don't need to set variables to `nil` in order to force ARC to free the referenced instance.

Another example:

```
class Son {}

class Father {
    var sons: [Son]
    init (sons: [Son]) {
        self.sons = sons
    }
}

func lifeGoesOn() {
    let son = Son()
    // here the referenceCout of the instance of Son is 1
    let father = Father(sons: [son])
    // here the referenceCount of the instance of Son is 2...

    // now variable son goes out of scope so the reatinCount of the instance of Son becomes 1
    // also father goes out of scope, so the variable father.sons goes out of scope as well, so the `retainCount` of the instance of Son becomes 0
    // and so both the instances of Father and Son gets freed
}
```

You can see this like a domino effect. When an instance is freed, all its references to other instances are removed. So the `retainCounts` of the referenced instances gets decreased. And if becomes `0` they are released. And so on...

### **3. Retain cycles**

Ok, what happen if I have 2 classes as follow?

```
class Son {
    let father:Father
    init(father:Father) {
        self.father = father
    }
}

class Father {
    var sons: [Son]
    init (sons: [Son]) {
        self.sons = sons
    }
}
```

Lets create now a reference from a `father` to its `son` and viceversa from the `son` to its `father`.

```
func lifeGoesOn() {
    var father = Father(sons:[])
    // retainCount of the instance of Father is 1
    var son = Son(father: father)
    // retainCount of the instance of Father is 2
    // retainCount of the instance of Son is 1
    father.sons.append(son)
    // retainCount of the instance of Father is 2
    // retainCount of the instance of Son is 2

    // Now we have a problem
}
```

At the of the function the father variable goes out of scope so the `retainCount` of the instance of `Father` becomes `1`.
Similarly the variable `son` goes out of scope and the `retainCount` of the instance of `Son` becomes `1`.

The problem here is that the instance of `Son` references the instance of `Father` (keeping this instance in alive memory). And the instance of `Father` references the instane of `Son`. These 2 instances should not be in memory anymore. They are not accessible by the programmer since all the variable to reference them are gone.

This is a problem.

### **4. Weak references**

When you structure your code you should pay attention to strong retain cycles. Let's how to refactor our code to fix this.

```
class Son {
    weak var father:Father?
    init(father:Father) {
        self.father = father
    }
}
```

Now the reference from a `Son` to its `Father` is `weak`. This means it does not count when ARC calculates the number of (strong) references to an instance. And this fix the problem seen in the previous paragraph.

I hope the subject is a little bit more clear now. There are several scenarios I did not cover. Again, the official documentation is pretty good and exhaustive.

### Update (to better answer the comment below)

If you have a custom `UIViewController` (lets call it `MyCustomViewController`) and this class has a strong property to an object let's see what happen.

```
class MyCustomViewController : UIViewController {
    var something = Something()
}

class Something {
    init() { // called when memory is allocated
        debugPrintln("The instance of Something has been created")
    }
    deinit { // called when memory is freed
        debugPrintln("The instance of Something has been freed")
    }
}
```

When you present a `MyCustomViewController`, an instance of `MyCustomViewController` is created. Then an instance of `Something` is created as well.

Now the instance of `MyCustomViewController` is referenced by the `UINavigationController` so has `retaintCount = 1`.
Similarly the instance of `Something` is referenced by the instance of `MyCustomViewController` so it has `retainCount = 1`.

So the instance of `UINavigationController` **keeps alive** the instance of `MyCustomViewController`. And the instance of `MyCustomViewController` **keeps alive** the instance of `Something`.

> UINavigationController -(strong)-> MyCustomViewController -(strong)->
>   Something

Next you decide to dismiss `MyCustomViewController`, so iOS animates it to leave the screen. When it is no longer visible it is removed the reference from the instance of `UINavigationController` to the instance `MyCustomViewController`.

> UINavigationController -(REMOVED)- MyCustomViewController -(strong)->
>   Something

This means that the `retainCount` of the instance of `MyCustomViewController` becomes 0 because: no one is referencing it now!

So the instance of `MyCustomViewController` is going to be removed from memory. In this process its properties are nulled.

> UINavigationController -(REMOVED)- [free memory] -(REMOVED)- Something

Now the `retainCount` of the instance of `Something` has become 0.
So it will be removed from memory as well.

> UINavigationController -(REMOVED)- [free memory] -(REMOVED)-> [free memory]

Finally, I overidden the `init` and `deinit` methods of `Something` so you can keep track of the allocation and deallocation of a related instance. Looking at the log (or using a breakpoint) you can verify what I said here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer...but in your 2nd point you were saying that when the references in a function gets automatically "nil" ,so we no need to to explicitly give "nil".   My question is that the references created inside a class (eg: UIviewcontroller class) will also die (made "nil") after the viewcontroller dissappears ??....I meant to ask when will the scope of a reference inside a class(Noe:not inside a function) will die??...Does it dies after we dismiss that view controller..??

Comment: Short answer is **YES**. When a `UIViewController` is dismissed (and then deallocated), the instances referenced only from it are **deallocated**. I am going to add a new paragraph to my answer to better detail this.

Comment: So just calling "dismissViewControllerAnimated" will not dealloc the **UIViewController** ?? as you have mentioned  In above statement - (and then deallocated)...if this is the case what is the way to dealloc the UIviewcontroller...is there any method ??

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is enough. After you call it the `UIViewController` is deallocated. If it does not happen it means there is another **strong reference** to the `UIViewController`.

Comment: Please take a look at the new paragraph I added to my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about view controller properties that are initialised by the view itself (such as `UILabel` or pretty much any subclass from `UIView` that you define in IB), Xcode will assign them as `weak` automatically, as the view (and not the view controller) have created the strong reference.

Most of the times you don't need to manually add `weak` to your properties, unless you have defined a strong relationship somewhere else in your code (which is the typical case when you have delegates).

Answer (score 0):

ARC mostly just works. You normally do not have to worry about declaring weak when using Cocoa classes such as the ones you listed.

You only have to consider it when you have different classes you've developed yourself that have bi-directional references. (Apartment class and Person class in [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)).